# How should a prof assign duty for a course with a discussion forum/board?

Tags: teaching, teaching-assistant, online-learning, covid-19, course-design

I am (with a few fellow TAs) helping a prof with an online course in STEM that has a discussion forum/board. However, it seems to me that this wasn't really thought through and now we have reached a very difficult situation in the course.

1. The prof assigned these duties to us on top of all the regular duties during the non-covid years, e.g., grading and tutorials. However, answering questions is a very unregulated task, which can easily go over-time depending on the difficulty of the more or less spontaneous question we get from the students.
2. We have 2 TAs answering question each week. However, my fellow TAs don't really care about answering questions (maybe they think it is a waste of their time?) and the bystander effect rans rampant among the course staffs (all waiting for someone else to answer). The prof do not enforce the TAs to answer questions.
3. All of us have to follow every minute detail about the course because the question can come from anywhere. This puts an enormous amount of pressure on us as compared to non-covid years, where all technical course related questions are assigned to one designated TA. Now all of us have to be experts in everything.
4. The students are not well trained on how to ask questions, and many questions essentially boils down to "my computer is doing the wrong thing, help!"
5. Aside from that, the students also ask a wide range of questions. TAs essentially have became personal tutors, online IT technicians, mental health professionals (to answer general grade-related concerns from stressed-out students), and career counselors.

As of right now, the discussion forum has entirely been taken over by questions left unanswered (and students do not bother to mark which question that has already been resolved, so we may be wasting our efforts). Where did things go so wrong and what can we do (in the future)?

Comment: Have you read your employment contract?

Comment: If students have mental health problem, you should refer them to an actual professional.  And it's quite likely they do have mental health problems.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist It has a vague section on "TA-student interaction time". It was something ridiculous like 6 hours in total, but we've spent way more than that already and its not even close to the end yet.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Depending on the severity we might have to copy and paste these bunch of mental health links and hotline numbers. Fortunately all we had to do so far was to reassure them everything will be ok, there will be grade-adjustments, etc.

Comment: You are obligated to follow the contract; if you have done that, now you can do what you want.  Managing the course is the professor's job.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I wish it was that easy. I've spent days/weeks grading poorly designed exams when I'm merely allocated hours and I was never compensated a penny extra, and I can't just say I don't want to grade anymore. Doing over-time seems to be the normal at my university. They just tell us to work faster.

Comment: "I've spent days/weeks grading poorly designed exams when I'm merely allocated hours and I was never compensated a penny extra,"  If it is required, that's a crime (in most locations).  Contact your union or local government.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask "How should a professor assign duty ..." which is really an unanswerable question.  I think the real question is "How can the team of TAs handle this workload in a way that is fair and not overwhelming?"

As other people have said in the comments, I think you need to set some boundaries about amount of time, but also that you will not answer all individual questions. For example say there are multiple questions about problem 8. You do one answer for all of them. That's one reason not to rush in immediately, rather wait until you see what the pattern of questions are.

It's a little hard to address this without knowing the subject matter or the kinds of questions. Also in covid times it is important to be kind to and understanding of  students and the way that technology challenges are now a hundred times greater.  Further, problems that used to be solved in 2 minutes during a live class now take hours, both for you and them.

I know you are limited by what your supervisor will allow but I'd like to make some suggestions.   But before that I will also say that it is okay for you to set boundaries on when you will answer questions and response times. Don't be mean, but explain. For example, maybe a TA will come in at noon every day and try to answer questions, and another will come at 6.

- First, discussion boards are not really a great way to do questions
  and answers, and definitely not for expert answers (and the TAs are
  the experts).  They can be great for **peer to peer support** and
  that's what I'd suggest you encourage.  Can you ask your supervisor
  if you could give extra credit (or even credit) for students who
  answer questions?  Or even without that, can you encourage students
  to jump in and help each other?  (I've found that my students can
  often answer the technology questions really well, maybe they have
  the same brand of phone or computer with the same OS which I don't
  have.)
- Second, notice on how Stack Exchange -- which is a set of sites
  devoted to answering questions -- there are well defined rules
  including obsessive refusal to answer duplicate questions.  Get
  yourself and the students in the habit of searching for an existing
  answer first. Teach them how to search effectively.

  Also, write up a document "how to ask a good question" and revise it
  as you get better at managing this. Put links to it everywhere.
- Third, build up your documentation and knowledge base. You could
  potentially use other features of your LMS for this (e.g. Blackboard
  has so many ways of doing things that no one can use them all).  For
  example, if the class is not using the wiki feature, start using
  that. Or you could use Google docs. Or a lot of other things. You
  could do FAQ but you can also start other things. Again, you can also
  get the students contributing if it makes sense. Also if you are
  answering questions that are strictly informational, post the
  information prewritten (or less good, with well described links) at
  the top of every page or in your signature. *Try to do this in a way
  that it can be used again next semester.*
- Fourth, teach students how to answer their own questions by showing
  how to find information online or in their textbook or syllabus.
  Many actually don't know how to use the index or table of contents of
  the text books. Or, for example, "I searched with keywords x, y, z
  and found this useful video."   This gets to asking good questions,
  but also, don't just answer, do things like say read page 329 and
  then come back with questions based on that.
- Fifth, once you have figured out how to actively sort questions where
  students are really having complicated problems from the rest,
  consider going into a meeting 1:1 or with a small group.  It's much,
  much easier to answer the questions that way because you go back and
  forth in real time.  If you record (and everyone involved is
  comfortable) you can also post the recording of the answer.
- Sixth, provide structure (and you may have to experiment with what
  works.  For example set up separate boards for questions about
  technology, questions about due dates and other syllabus related
  issues, and then questions about each topic or chapter and then you
  can have others like "careers" and "random."
- Seventh, have some prewritten templates so you can just fill in specific information.

I'm sure that there are lots of other things you can do too.